# How do i know when a download fails codenameone downloadUrlToFileSystemInBackground

Tags: java, codenameone

My download may fail but the incomplete file is still in FileStorage how do i delete the file if the download fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic error handling code for errors is still invoked in the network manager so you can still get an event on that. In your `init(Object)` method do this:

```
addNetworkErrorListener(err -> { 
    // prevent the event from propagating
    err.consume();
    if(err.getError() != null) {
        Log.e(err.getError());
    }
    Log.sendLogAsync();
    Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
});
```

Notice that this code is there by default for new projects https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-default-code.html

Another approach would be:

```
if(!Util.downloadUrlToFile(url, fileName, false)) {
   // error in download
}
```

Notice that this is a blocking method so you can wrap it in a `callSerially` if you don't want that.

Comment: Hi shai, this worked for connectionRequests but did not work for  Util.downloadUrlToFile because when downloading large files and the internet is bad(which is common in my country for now) so how do i handle when  Util.downloadUrlToFile does not download completely and i need to delete the incomplete downloaded file because of a network error?

Comment: That should work but I added another option to do that